# How do you configure a method-entry-point-resolver for a method with InboundHeader annotations in a java component?

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have the following component defined in my flow:

```
  <component doc:name="GraduationService">
      <method-entry-point-resolver>
          <include-entry-point method="getGraduationDatesWithPidmOrStudentId"/>
      </method-entry-point-resolver>
      <spring-object bean="graduationService" />
  </component>
```

I am trying to call the 'getGraduationDatesWithPidmOrStudentId' method defined in the 'graduationService' bean.  Here is what the method signature looks like:

```
public Object getGraduationDatesWithPidmOrStudentId(@Payload Payload payload,
    @InboundHeaders("studentId") String studentId, 
    @InboundHeaders("pidm") String pidm ) {  ....... }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Message               : Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
ExplicitMethodEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "edu.ucdavis.iet.apis.students.graduation.service.GraduationService" with arguments: "{class java.lang.String}"
]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-321
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
ExplicitMethodEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "edu.ucdavis.iet.apis.students.graduation.service.GraduationService" with arguments: "{class java.lang.String}"
] (org.mule.model.resolvers.EntryPointNotFoundException)
  org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet:49 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/model/resolvers/EntryPointNotFoundException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.model.resolvers.EntryPointNotFoundException: Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
ExplicitMethodEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "edu.ucdavis.iet.apis.students.graduation.service.GraduationService" with arguments: "{class java.lang.String}"
]
    at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:49)
    at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:339)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:82)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

If I remove the Annotations for InboundHeaders and change the '@Payload Payload payload' to '@Payload String payload', I can't at least get this to resolve the method.  I don't seem to understand how the @InboundHeader annotations are supposed to work, then.

Answer (score 0):

When working with annotations you don't need to specifically set an entry point resolver as it will use the AnnotatedEntryPointResolver under the hood.

So the following will work:

```
public Object getGraduationDatesWithPidmOrStudentId(@Payload String payload,
    @InboundHeaders("studentId") String studentId, 
    @InboundHeaders("pidm") String pidm ) {  ....... }
```

And:

```
<component doc:name="GraduationService">
     <spring-object bean="graduationService" />
</component>
```

Also you can specifically set it using:

```
<component>
   <custom-entry-point-resolver class="org.mule.impl.model.resolvers.AnnotatedEntryPointResolver" />
   <spring-object bean="graduationService" />
</component>
```

Also note you don't need to set the payload to an instance of Payload. Mule will try and transform the payload to match the parameter type.